# How can I change the text from a TextBlock in a SplitView.Pane from a page loaded into a Frame?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

my MainPage have a SplitView, and I load into the Frame of the SplitView my StartPage.

How can I access the xaml objects in the MainPage from my StartPage, for example:

How can I change the text of the TextBlock User in the SplitView.Pane from the Start Page

MainPage xaml:

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="Inline" IsPaneOpen="True" OpenPaneLength="243">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel Background="#222d32" Padding="10,20">
            <TextBlock x:Name="User" Foreground="#ffffff" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <Frame Name="MainFrame">

    </Frame>
</SplitView>
```

MainPage cs:

```
this.InitializeComponent();
MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(StartPage));
```

StartPage cs:

```
public sealed partial class StartPage : Page
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the TextBlock field public using the `x:FieldModifier="public"` on it. Then you can access it from another classes but you need the instance of your MainPage class. I use a static property in my apps for that.

```
public static MainPage Current { get; private set; }
```

And in you MainPage constructor you have to assign it like this:

```
Current = this;
```

Then you can set the Text property on your TextBlock from another classes using this:

```
MainPage.Current.User.Text = "new text";
```